# Dockerfile: error: 'docker-php-ext-install' does not exist and extension does not exist

Tags: php, docker

I'm trying to install some PHP extensions when building a php-apache image. Here's the `./php/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath \
        docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-enable calendar \
        docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd \
        docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt \
        docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql \
        docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli \
        docker-php-ext-install soap && docker-php-ext-enable soap \
        docker-php-ext-install sockets && docker-php-ext-enable sockets \
        docker-php-ext-install exif && docker-php-ext-enable exif \
        docker-php-ext-install wddx && docker-php-ext-enable wddx \
        docker-php-ext-install wmlrpc && docker-php-ext-enable wmlrpc \
        docker-php-ext-install zip && docker-php-ext-enable zip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

And here's the `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  php-apache-environment:
    container_name: php-apache
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./php/src:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 80:80
  db:
    container_name: db
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      MYSQL_DATABASE: MYSQL_DATABASE
      MYSQL_USER: MYSQL_USER
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: MYSQL_PASSWORD
    ports:
      - "9906:3306"
```

And when I run `docker-compose up -d`, this is the error given to me:

```
error: 'docker-php-ext-install' does not exist

usage: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable [options] module-name [module-name ...]
   ie: /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable gd mysqli
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable pdo pdo_mysql
       /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable --ini-name 0-apc.ini apcu apc

Possible values for module-name:
bcmath.so opcache.so sodium.so

Some of the above modules are already compiled into PHP; please check
the output of "php -i" to see which modules are already loaded.
The command '/bin/sh -c docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath   docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-enable calendar      docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd    docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt   docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql     docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli   docker-php-ext-install soap && docker-php-ext-enable soap      docker-php-ext-install sockets && docker-php-ext-enable sockets  docker-php-ext-install exif && docker-php-ext-enable exif       docker-php-ext-install wddx && docker-php-ext-enable wddx       docker-php-ext-install wmlrpc && docker-php-ext-enable wmlrpc   docker-php-ext-install zip && docker-php-ext-enable zip' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'php-apache-environment' failed to build : Build failed
```

What is wrong in here?

I tried to use all absolute paths like this:

```
RUN /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-install calendar && /usr/local/bin/docker-php-ext-enable calendar \
```

But then it gives me errors like these:

```
error: 'calendar' does not exist
error: 'gd' does not exist
error: 'mcrypt' does not exist
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `&&` at the end of each line of the long `RUN` command in the Dockerfile, before `\`.

```
FROM php:8.0-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath && \
        docker-php-ext-install calendar && docker-php-ext-enable calendar && \
        docker-php-ext-install gd && docker-php-ext-enable gd && \
        docker-php-ext-install mcrypt && docker-php-ext-enable mcrypt && \
        docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && docker-php-ext-enable pdo_mysql && \
        docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli && \
        docker-php-ext-install soap && docker-php-ext-enable soap && \
        docker-php-ext-install sockets && docker-php-ext-enable sockets && \
        docker-php-ext-install exif && docker-php-ext-enable exif && \
        docker-php-ext-install wddx && docker-php-ext-enable wddx && \
        docker-php-ext-install wmlrpc && docker-php-ext-enable wmlrpc && \
        docker-php-ext-install zip && docker-php-ext-enable zip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y
```

Also, extensions should be enabled by default, there is no need to run `docker-php-ext-enable`, at least with the PHP-FPM images.

One more thing, even with these modifications, your build will likely fail because of missing dependencies and/or unknown extensions (if some are already in the base image).

For instance, `gd` will need `zlib`, so you must install these dependencies before installing the extensions (`apt update && apt install -y ...`).